# lambda and linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am working on an asp.net mvc 5 application and I am trying to filter a list but I'll always get a bad result when I have a multiple selection. Im using a simple form with checkboxes to know which mission's criteria is selected.

My Database:

Table Mission has a list of criteria (Table: CriteriaList)

```
// public virtual ICollection<Criteria> CriteriaList { get; set; }

int[] CriteriaSelected = List of criteria selected in the form

var items = from i in db.Missions select i;

foreach (var criteriaID in CriteriaSelected)
{
  items = items.Where(m => m.CriteriaList.Any(c => c.CriteriaID == criteriaID ));
}
```

I know it might be a problem with the 'and' operator used to concatenate the multiple "where" because I got the right result just for one checkbox selected. But I'm right now a little lost to do a multiple selection of criteria

Your help is really appreciated

Comment: Please be aware that you code has nothing to do with asp.net mvc.  Mvc has no *data access* within the framework.  Most likely you are using Entity Framework.

Comment: You are completely right, I tried to give the more information i could to help and didnt notice it was not related to asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try:

```
var items = db.Missions.Where(m => m.CriteriaList
                                    .Any(c => CriteriaSelected.Contains(c.CriteriaID )));
```

You should get every mission where at least one of the criteria in the list is found in the selected criterias.

But be aware, that this is not with good performance with too much records because of lots of list searches.

Comment: Thx a lot loiti, it worked, do you know if there's another way better for the performance ?

Comment: @dincan Since this is actually being turned into SQL by EF I doubt you need to be worried about performance.

Answer (score 0):

@loiti was close, but deleted his answer instead of revising it. Here's what you need:

```
var criteriaSelectedIds = CriteriaSelected.Select(s => s.CriteriaID);
var items = db.Missions.Where(m =>
    m.CriteriaList.Any(c =>
        criteriaSelectedIds.Contains(c.CriteriaID)
    )
);
```